# MEAN stack - How do I retrieve a data subset based on user?

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, subset, mean-stack

I'm retrieving datapoints by mongoose from a collection of the form:

```
{
"_id":"1",
"creator": 
    {"_id":"a",
     "username":"aaa",
     "name":"aaa"},
"comment":"",
"value":10,
"created":"2016-05-28T12:09:25.666Z"},
{
"_id":"2",
"creator":
    {"_id":"b",
     "username":"bbb",
     "name":"bbb"},
"comment":"",
"value":100,
"created":"2016-05-28T09:13:18.361Z"}
```

...

Where each datapoint is defined by a Schema and creator is defined by a separate Schema. 
I'm able to retrieve all datapoints via angular by using the resource query method:

```
    $scope.find = function() {
         $scope.datapoints = Datapoints.query();
        };
```

I would now like to retrieve only those datapoints corresponding to the specific user (whose details are accessible through $scope.authentication.user).

Failed attempts include:

```
    $scope.findByUser = function() {
            user = $scope.authentication.user;
            $scope.datapoints = Datapoints.query({creator:user});
    };
```

or:

```
    $scope.findByUser = function() {
        Datapoints.query(function(result) {
            $scope.datapoints = $filter('filter')(result, {creator: $scope.authentication.user});
        });
```

or:

```
    $scope.findByUser = function() {
        $scope.datapoints = Datapoints.query();
        $scope.datapoints = $filter('filter')($scope.datapoint, {creator: $scope.authentication.user});
    };
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you filtering in the frontend? Can't you access the current authenticated user in the backend and make your api controller to fetch only the datapoints corresponding to the currently logged in user?

Comment: I agree that is the smarter way to go about it. Took me a couple of days but eventually figured it out. Thanks!